# Drivers not working

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

Im trying to make driver for shapekeys but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Basically when I add driver to the shapekey it's shown as "mute" in the drivers editor and it doesn't work. I tried right clicking and using unmute option but it didn't work at all. Im sending the example blend. file that shows the problem. So if you know how to fix this issue or have any better way to add drivers then please respond.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Adding screenshots of your drivers in the driver editor would be helpful.  A blend file with an example would be more helpful. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to drive the value of the shapekey.  Instead, you drove the value of the "mute shapekey" checkbox.  That's what "mute" means here, technically "mute (Key 1)"-- the property that you're driving is muting key 1.

Muting a shapekey disables it.  So when the local Z location of your bone is at 0, the shapekey is not muted (mute set to 0), but the shapekey is still 0.0, so you don't see anything.  When the local Z location of your bone is at 1, the shapekey *is* muted, and in addition the shapekey value is still 0.0, because that's not being driven.

You just drove the wrong property.  What you want to drive is the value of the shapekey, pointed out below by the tooltip:

[image]

The easiest way to do that is to right click in that field and "Add Driver."  Don't forget to delete the driver for the mute box.